# PhantomJS is not returning the page source

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I have PhantomJS 1.9.0 installed.

I tried the following code to download the page and show the HTML.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=['--ignore-ssl-   errors=true'])
page = driver.get('http://example.com')
print(page.page_source)
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/python3.4 phantom.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "phantom.py", line 5, in <module>
print(page.page_source)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'page_source'
```

Clearly it means that driver.get isn't working but the reason?

Comment: get is an issue an inplace operation, just call get then print 
driver.get_source

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're calling the `page_source` attribute on the `page` variable, which is incorrect. All the `get` method does is navigate to the URL specified in the parameter, but it does not return anything to be stored in the `page` variable, which is why the error indicates it is a NoneType object. What you need to do is call the attribute on the `driver` variable.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true'])
print(driver.page_source)
```

Answer (score 1):

I currently don't have a good explanation as to why, but assigning page like that doesn't work for some reason

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true'])
driver.get('http://example.com')
html_content = driver.page_source
print(html_content)
driver.close()
```

I'm going to keep looking and go read the documentation to see if I can find out why this is

Comment: Thanks for the response. I update the code but now I am getting the error that 'Message: Can not connect to the Service /usr/bin/phantomjs'. I have it installed already. phantomjs is at /usr/bin/phantomjs

Comment: @conquester be mindful of your spacing and you should be ok `--ignore-ssl-errors=true` it's all one hyphenated arg

Comment: Thanks for that. I totally missed it!